# How to compile C code on server from client in PHP

Tags: php

Is it possible in PHP to send C source file as REQUEST then server will compile the source file and send the compiled EXE file as RESPONSE. Finally when the client receives the exe, it will be automatically executed on his machine. so that, client can compile codes without having compiler.

Comment: `it will be automatically executed on his machine` security flaw? what security flaw?

Comment: **When you compiled it to an .exe, the client's machine doesn't require an installed C Compiler.** - They just execute the file?

Comment: no. actually I want to develop an web application where people can compile code & see the result instantly.

Comment: If you wanna do that, you execute the code in some kind of **sandbox** on your server, and simply **return the output**.

Comment: @Xatenev: it would need any runtimes that a compiler may produce dependencies on.

Comment: This is like an online coding competition. where students will compile the code as client. u know what I'm trying to say..!!

Answer (score 0):

If you use Linux server try shell_exec to run gcc by which you can compile client side code in server and can send the output too to the client.